# Is execution_date the date of the DAG run or the Task run?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is the value of `execution_date` the time date/time when the DAG ran--and is it the same value for all of its Tasks--or is `execution_date` (potentially) different per Task within a DAG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `execution_date` is the start of the interval for the run. All tasks have the same `execution_date` value as their run. It's how they're associated with a run in the code.

Think of it like this: If you ran a process quarterly and generated a report from data for that quarter, would you name the report for the quarter you were in *when you created the file*, or for the quarter the data in the report is from? That's what the `execution_date` is.