# how to get airflow schedule right

Tags: etl, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I found very confusing about how the airflow schedule works.
I would like to schedule a dag that runs on Friday and I would like use its result on Saturday. So I did the crontab expression like this: `00 16 * * 5`, however, as of today 2020-03-10, the last execution date I got from airflow run is 2020-02-28. This is not desired as the most recent Friday is actually 2020-03-06,  I couldn't get the 2020-03-06 to run unless I schedule it every day and skip it if it is not Friday. Is there a way to do this schedule right?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people get confused by how Airflow's `execution_date` and `schedule_interval` values work, namely that it waits  for a period of time to "close" before it'll execute for that period; here's a portion from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53330467/174652) I gave:

> Think of it like this: If you ran a process quarterly and generated a report from data for that quarter, would you name the report for the quarter you were in *when you created the file*, or for the quarter the data in the report is from? That's what the `execution_date` is.

Try changing your `start_date` to be less one whole schedule interval. It should run on 03/06 but its `execution_date` will say `02/28`